# What's the word for this geometric solid?

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

What's the word for a geometric solid with two congruent regular pentagons in parallel planes and ten congruent triangles on lateral faces?

It's neither a pyramid nor a prism.

I chose pentagons arbitrarily. It seems to me there is a word for such a figure in general, proper with any number of sides on the bases.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: MathsSE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have described an *[antiprism](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Antiprism.html)*:

> A semiregular polyhedron constructed with 2 n-gons and 2n triangles.

(Weisstein, Eric W. "[Antiprism](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Antiprism.html)." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource.)

Comment: Couldn't have imagined faster service.